# how to show text when hover over an image

Tags: javascript, html

how do I make a text like this show up once I hover over an image? some tumblr themes have this same feature too so i wonder how do you do it [heres an example of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVeEl.gif)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can answer your question better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```css
.container{
width:200px;
height:200px;
  text-align:center;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  position: relative;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
img{
width:200px;
height:200px;
}
img:hover + .hide {
  display: block;
}

 .hide:hover{
  animation: color-change 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes color-change {
  0% { color: orange; }
  50% { color: green; }
  75% { color: yellow; }
  100% { color: lightblue; }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/W0cq73T.jpg">
<div class="hide">this text will be shown when someone hovers the image</div>
</div>
```

so basically you set the text to `display:none` to hide the text.
And set it to `display:block` to show the text when someone hovers it, javascript is not needed at all

and now you can use the `animation` to animate the color of the text  like in the video when someone hovers the text

Comment: @anon i hope this helps

Comment: is there a way to make my text be on the center? thank you btw!

Comment: @anon i have edited my answer and the text should be at the center now you can take  look at the edited answer, im pretty sure that is what you want

Comment: @anon let me know if you have any other doubts

Answer (score 0):

```js
let test = document.getElementById("test");
test.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
  // highlight the mouseover target
  event.target.style.color = "orange";

  // reset the color after a short delay
  setTimeout(function() {
    event.target.style.color = "";
  }, 500);
}, false);
```

```css
#center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: url('https://www.iso.org/files/live/sites/isoorg/files/news/News_archive/2017/08/Ref2213/Ref2213.jpg/thumbnails/300x300');
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<div id="center">
  <p>Te<span id="test">ss</span>s</p>
</div>
```